# Trying to find out what language this was created in (pic inside)

Tags: terminal

You can see the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABWc4.jpg

I use this system for work on my home PC and I'm trying to find out what language it is, and if I can extract data from it. Someone suggested it may be some type of terminal program that is then converted to web. It is used like a terminal, using the F keys to help navigate.

The only info I have is that it's called CATS. It is used by the company to keep in touch with employees, keep track of payroll/payments, see when you work next, etc.

Comment: Would be nice if you could click the gray tick mark next to the correct answer :) 
The little I know has finally gone to good use lol.

Comment: Well it wasn't really write. Sure it's html/javascript to display the content but that's not how everything is done.

Comment: Oh, okay. But your link clearly says html at the end, and the question would otherwise be too broad, because it could be any language.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's HTML/ XHTML. Can read that off from the end of the link.

The functioning of page is handled by Javascript

Comment: But it acts kinda like a terminal. Like all the f keys are used. Someone suggested it's terminal but just converted to HTML for display. It's a pretty complicated system, I don't think it's anything basic.

Comment: Maybe that just javascript acting on the functioning side? I may be wrong, but to me it seems possible.

Comment: I don't know much about programming, but think there is javascript involved.

Comment: Yup, I mentioned that in the comment above. Looks like my answers right. :)

Comment: But could that be just what is used to display it for web? Not the actual language? This system is decades old, it's definitely not simply html/javascript.

Comment: Well, that could be the CSS pushing in the style? HTML has been there for quite some time I believe.